# Binding ObservbleCollection to Combo box in XAML - Windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to bind an `ObservableCollection` variable to a `ComboBox` in the XAML. The data is not binding.

**XAML File**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCity" Height="44" Width="150" Grid.Row="4" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding lstCity}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**Code behind (After navigating to another page)**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{  
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.UserName = "Gayathri";
    userInfo.Country = "India";
    userInfo.State = "TN";    
    ObservableCollection<string> cityInfo = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    cityInfo.Add("Chennai");
    cityInfo.Add("Cuddalore");
    cityInfo.Add("Pondicherry");
    cityInfo.Add("Villupuram");    
    userInfo.lstCity = cityInfo;    
    this.DataContext = userInfo;
}
```

Here I am passing values in the `DataContext`. The data is getting bound to the `textbox` but not the `Combobox`.

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bindings are slightly wrong.
They should be like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCity" Height="44" Width="150" Grid.Row="4" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding lstCity}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

(I've moved the reference to `lstCity`)

Previously you were binding the whole DataContext to the ComboBox and then each TextBlock to the Collection of strings.
You need to bind the ItemsSource of the ComboBox to the collection and then each TextBlock should contain one of the strings.

Comment: @user2115618 If this solves the issue please mark it as an answer ;)